# Can you have PHP variable inside a button onclick tag?

Tags: php, html

```
    echo'<button type="button" id="buttonNext" onclick="window.location.href = \'http://index.php?page=\'+\'.$phpVariableHere. \';">Next page</button>'
```

So is it possible, i can't get it working.

Comment: Yes, you can.  Though mixing *three different languages* on *one line of code* is definitely a recipe for quoting errors.  More to the point though, what happens when you use this code?  Do you get an error from PHP?  If so, what is that error?  If not, what is the resulting output in the page source?  How specifically is this failing?

Comment: Maybe the reason u are getting so many downvotes is that: Your question has no text, u can share your effort, why u need this code to work this way, what is the error u are getting. These all will have an impact on the responses u will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting confused with the string-ception happening. It might be worth taking a look at the [PHP documentation for strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

I think you are looking for the following:

```php
echo '<button type="button" id="buttonNext" onclick="window.location.href=\'http://index.php?page=' . $phpVariableHere . '\'" />';
```

Just be mindful where you are starting your quotes and also where escaped quotes need to start and end.

It might be better to reverse your quote order here and start with the double quote `"` just so the JavaScript side becomes less mentally taxing.

```php
echo "<button type=\"button\" id=\"buttonNext\" onclick=\"window.location.href='http://index.php?page=$phpVariableHere'\" />";
```

Just note in this case you will need to escape all your HTML attributes instead.